# Side column slider for mobile

Tags: jquery, mobile, slider

I'm tring to make a side column similar to facebook. I tried to use this plugin but is not compatible 100% with mobile version. [Page Slide](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/pageslide/), I would like have a side column with a search filed as well. Any suggest about some plugin or script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is what you're after?

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/panels/#